# moving an Image Button in the action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am creating a custom action bar.
it looks good but i have a wierd problem, for some reason the ImageButton on the right side is stuck and I can't seem to move it with margins.
this is my layout - custom_actionbar.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawerButton"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/drawer_button"
    android:background="@null"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favouritesButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_important" />
```

and my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

    ImageButton drawer = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.drawerButton);
    drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawer Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    ImageButton favButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.favouritesButton);
    favButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fav Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

you can click on the link below to see how it is right now.

[picture of how it is right now](http://cl.ly/image/0w3j3P0u0b3x)

I need to move the "star" icon 8dp to the left.
the margin works in the navigation drawer icon but for some reason it doesn't work for the right icon.
he is too close to the right side of the screen.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance, Refael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the view's layout params when setting the custom view, like so

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, layoutParams);
```

If that doesn't work, try to specify in you custom view's relative layout this

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

Comment: Hi Joao, this doesn't seems to work, LayoutParams seems to make an error "cannot find symbol class LayoutParams".
and the "layout_gravity", tried that one aswell, not doing anything differently either.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I forgot to add the parent class there. I edited my answer. Try again.

Comment: Hi again Joao, thanks a lot for trying to help.
although it's still not working.
error in logcat - "method ActionBar.setCustomView is not applicable

Comment: I didn't realize setCustomView expects ActionBar.LayoutParams. Again, I edited my answer. Try again :) Be careful when importing. If you're using the support library import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`, otherwise import `android.app.ActionBar`

Comment: dear mister Joao Sousa.. THANK YOU !
problem solved and all thanks to you!
I really appreciate it buddy, cheers!